# Pandas' `to_sql` errors with pre-1970 dates

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running into an error when using `pandas`'s `to_sql` function with an SQLite DB. It appears that, when there are date columns with dates before 1970 (the start of UNIX epoch), the insert fails. Would anyone know a solution or a workaround to this problem?

I'm using Python 3.9 with `pandas` 2.1.0 on Windows 10.

```py
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

con = sqlite3.connect("test_db.db")

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["2020-01-01", "2023-05-12", "1967-05-31"]})
df["b"] = pd.to_datetime(df["b"])

df.to_sql("test_table", con, if_exists="append")
#> Traceback (most recent call last):
#> Cell In[8], line 1
#> ----> 1 df.to_sql("test_table", con, if_exists="append")
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:333, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
#>     327 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
#>     328     warnings.warn(
#>     329         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
#>     330         FutureWarning,
#>     331         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
#>     332     )
#> --> 333 return func(*args, **kwargs)
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:3008, in NDFrame.to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
#>    2813 """
#>    2814 Write records stored in a DataFrame to a SQL database.
#>    2815 
#>    (...)
#>    3004 [(1,), (None,), (2,)]
#>    3005 """  # noqa: E501
#>    3006 from pandas.io import sql
#> -> 3008 return sql.to_sql(
#>    3009     self,
#>    3010     name,
#>    3011     con,
#>    3012     schema=schema,
#>    3013     if_exists=if_exists,
#>    3014     index=index,
#>    3015     index_label=index_label,
#>    3016     chunksize=chunksize,
#>    3017     dtype=dtype,
#>    3018     method=method,
#>    3019 )
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:788, in to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method, engine, **engine_kwargs)
#>     783     raise NotImplementedError(
#>     784         "'frame' argument should be either a Series or a DataFrame"
#>     785     )
#>     787 with pandasSQL_builder(con, schema=schema, need_transaction=True) as pandas_sql:
#> --> 788     return pandas_sql.to_sql(
#>     789         frame,
#>     790         name,
#>     791         if_exists=if_exists,
#>     792         index=index,
#>     793         index_label=index_label,
#>     794         schema=schema,
#>     795         chunksize=chunksize,
#>     796         dtype=dtype,
#>     797         method=method,
#>     798         engine=engine,
#>     799         **engine_kwargs,
#>     800     )
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2443, in SQLiteDatabase.to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype, method, engine, **engine_kwargs)
#>    2433 table = SQLiteTable(
#>    2434     name,
#>    2435     self,
#>    (...)
#>    2440     dtype=dtype,
#>    2441 )
#>    2442 table.create()
#> -> 2443 return table.insert(chunksize, method)
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:1059, in SQLTable.insert(self, chunksize, method)
#>    1056     break
#>    1058 chunk_iter = zip(*(arr[start_i:end_i] for arr in data_list))
#> -> 1059 num_inserted = exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
#>    1060 # GH 46891
#>    1061 if num_inserted is not None:
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2139, in SQLiteTable._execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter)
#>    2137 def _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter) -> int:
#>    2138     data_list = list(data_iter)
#> -> 2139     conn.executemany(self.insert_statement(num_rows=1), data_list)
#>    2140     return conn.rowcount
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2094, in SQLiteTable._register_date_adapters.<locals>.<lambda>(val)
#>    2092 adapt_date_iso = lambda val: val.isoformat()
#>    2093 adapt_datetime_iso = lambda val: val.isoformat()
#> -> 2094 adapt_datetime_epoch = lambda val: int(val.timestamp())
#>    2096 sqlite3.register_adapter(time, _adapt_time)
#>    2098 sqlite3.register_adapter(date, adapt_date_iso)
#> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

df = df.drop([2])
df.to_sql("test_table", con, if_exists="append")
#> 2
```

EDIT: In 3.11:

```py
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

con = sqlite3.connect("test_db.db")

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["2020-01-01", "2023-05-12", "1967-05-31"]})
df["b"] = pd.to_datetime(df["b"])

df.to_sql("test_table", con, if_exists="append")
#> Traceback (most recent call last):
#> Cell In[8], line 1
#> ----> 1 df.to_sql("test_table", con, if_exists="append")
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:333, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
#>     327 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
#>     328     warnings.warn(
#>     329         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
#>     330         FutureWarning,
#>     331         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
#>     332     )
#> --> 333 return func(*args, **kwargs)
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:3008, in NDFrame.to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
#>    2813 """
#>    2814 Write records stored in a DataFrame to a SQL database.
#>    2815 
#>    (...)
#>    3004 [(1,), (None,), (2,)]
#>    3005 """  # noqa: E501
#>    3006 from pandas.io import sql
#> -> 3008 return sql.to_sql(
#>    3009     self,
#>    3010     name,
#>    3011     con,
#>    3012     schema=schema,
#>    3013     if_exists=if_exists,
#>    3014     index=index,
#>    3015     index_label=index_label,
#>    3016     chunksize=chunksize,
#>    3017     dtype=dtype,
#>    3018     method=method,
#>    3019 )
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:788, in to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method, engine, **engine_kwargs)
#>     783     raise NotImplementedError(
#>     784         "'frame' argument should be either a Series or a DataFrame"
#>     785     )
#>     787 with pandasSQL_builder(con, schema=schema, need_transaction=True) as pandas_sql:
#> --> 788     return pandas_sql.to_sql(
#>     789         frame,
#>     790         name,
#>     791         if_exists=if_exists,
#>     792         index=index,
#>     793         index_label=index_label,
#>     794         schema=schema,
#>     795         chunksize=chunksize,
#>     796         dtype=dtype,
#>     797         method=method,
#>     798         engine=engine,
#>     799         **engine_kwargs,
#>     800     )
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2443, in SQLiteDatabase.to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype, method, engine, **engine_kwargs)
#>    2433 table = SQLiteTable(
#>    2434     name,
#>    2435     self,
#>    (...)
#>    2440     dtype=dtype,
#>    2441 )
#>    2442 table.create()
#> -> 2443 return table.insert(chunksize, method)
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:1059, in SQLTable.insert(self, chunksize, method)
#>    1056     break
#>    1058 chunk_iter = zip(*(arr[start_i:end_i] for arr in data_list))
#> -> 1059 num_inserted = exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
#>    1060 # GH 46891
#>    1061 if num_inserted is not None:
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2139, in SQLiteTable._execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter)
#>    2137 def _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter) -> int:
#>    2138     data_list = list(data_iter)
#> -> 2139     conn.executemany(self.insert_statement(num_rows=1), data_list)
#>    2140     return conn.rowcount
#> File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:2094, in SQLiteTable._register_date_adapters.<locals>.<lambda>(val)
#>    2092 adapt_date_iso = lambda val: val.isoformat()
#>    2093 adapt_datetime_iso = lambda val: val.isoformat()
#> -> 2094 adapt_datetime_epoch = lambda val: int(val.timestamp())
#>    2096 sqlite3.register_adapter(time, _adapt_time)
#>    2098 sqlite3.register_adapter(date, adapt_date_iso)
#> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

df = df.drop([2])
df.to_sql("test_table", con, if_exists="append")
#> 2
```

Comment: Why such an old Python version? The current version is 3.11 with 3.12 coming in October 2023. 3.10 and 3.11 have far better error messages

Comment: I’ve tried with 3.11 with the same outcome (including the contents of the error message).

Comment: What columns are in your table? The problem might be that since the table already exists pandas is forced to do some extra conversions that fail. Try to insert in a table that does not exist and see if the error still occurs

Comment: @MatteoZanoni this is a known Pandas bug. In previous Pandas versions mixed data wouldn't affect Pandas at all. It would save dates as strings even if the storage class was INTEGER

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it was what I suspected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this *after* upgrading to Pandas 2.1.0 exactly. I couldn't reproduce this with earlier versions even after manually creating a table with `INTEGER` columns *and* existing data. Before Pandas 2.1.0, dates would be stored as ISO8601 strings no matter what the storage class was.

This is [a known bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54877) - instead of storing dates as ISO8601 date strings in SQLite, Pandas 2.1.0 is trying to store them as Unix epochs. Previous versions would save them as ISO8601 strings. This is more serious than a runtime error.

The fix will come in 2.1.1 but until then using SQLAlchemy removes the error:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> con = create_engine('sqlite:///test_db.db', echo=False)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["2020-01-01", "2023-05-12", "1967-05-31"]})
>>> df["b"] = pd.to_datetime(df["b"])
>>> df.to_sql("test_table", con, if_exists="append")
3
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense - will use the SQLAlchemy workaround. I did find that issue, but since the wording of my error was a little bit different, I didn't realize it was related.

Comment: @Skumin yes, you have to get the versions and modules just wrong to reproduce this.